# Opengraph extensions rendering

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'm using these extensions:

- jh_opengraphprotocol *(let's call it jh_protocol for short)*
- jh_opengraph_ttnews *(call it jh_ttnews)*

Problem is, jh_protocol og:tags render *after* jh_ttnews. jh_ttnews should be rendered last, since they are more specific. If there are more of the same og:tag, crawler will pick the last one.

Both extensions render in this way:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData[$this->extKey] = $this->renderHeaderLines($og);
```

I guess jh_protocol come first only because it's alphabetically first. But I need to change that. Or disable jh_protocol on specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just disable the jh_opengraphprotocol for the news detail page using typoscript in order to render og:tags only once.